# Can moderators see the close/reopen _votes_ (and _not_ the reviews)?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits, moderator-abilities, voting-limits

Yes I know, mods (and 10k+ users) can see others' reviews, including the close/reopen reviews.

But what if a close or reopen vote happens from any review indepently? As I can see, in this case it doesn't create/change a *review* entitiy, only creates a *vote* entity, which are probably completely different things in the SE software.

Can mods see the close/reopen votes?

*Extension:* I am asking about the *individual* close-reopen votes, not from their counts (which is visible for anybody over 3k+).

Comment: Anyone with close vote privilege (3000 rep normally) can see how many close votes there are on a question and what the close vote reasons are, no matter whether they came from review or from looking directly at the question and voting on it. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @RobertLongson No, I am about the _induvidual_ close-reopen votes (which in the case of the up/down votes is hidden even from the diamond mods).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, diamond moderators have access to a special timeline **on posts** which does list all close and reopen votes (and who cast them) inside it, including any that have expired or otherwise no longer count. Close and reopen votes are the *only* votes that they see in that timeline, though. This information proved valuable to me, as a moderator on Stack Overflow, countless times in determining what happened with a question, whether it be related to review or not.

Moderators do not have access to go to a user's profile and look at all the close and reopen votes a user has cast (because they don't have access to the votes tab on your profile).

Non-diamond users cannot see anything about close and reopen votes outside of the count that is provided in the link and the names provided in the revision history.

Answer (score 4):

The system has changed a little. Now, moderators can see:

- All close/reopen/delete/undelete votes in the timeline of a question (like before, but now the timeline is easier to access). This includes aged away or retracted votes.
- All close/reopen/delete/undelete votes cast by a single user. It is the very interface shown in [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure) but without the upvote/downvote tabs. (See [Allow moderators to view close and delete vote history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380703/323179))

To be extra clear, moderators cannot see your individual upvotes or downvotes anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know there is no global Close/Reopen votes list and moderators don't have access to the live database.

Moderators might be able to see Close/Reopen votes cast by a specific user, and probably can see who cast Close/Reopen votes on a question. (I know for sure they can see who cast flags)

10k users can indeed see who cast what in the review history, but it's complicated to search, and there is no link from a question to its relevant review item. So generally speaking, 10k users who are not diamond moderators can't really know who cast Close/Reopen votes on a question.

Comment: Until the question is actually closed/reopened of course, at which point anyone can see.

Comment: @RobertLongson good point, but still - it won't show publicly in the closers' profiles, or in any public list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard finding the review item is [easy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306407/how-to-open-the-corresponding-review-item-when-viewing-a-question-answer/306412#306412)

Comment: @rene still requires messing around with userscripts and all  but yeah, never said it wasn't possible. :)